# which J2EE IDE support tomcat-8.5.11 and JDK 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

i want to use tomcat-8.5.11(64-bit windows) and jdk-7u80-windows-x64 for creating web-application so which J2EE support both version.

i use Neon J2EE 64-bit but it gives error while open eclipse it required JDK-8 version.

so i want to configure tomcat-8.5 server and java compiler jdk-1.7 in eclipse.

Comment: Why are you still trying to develop stuff for the Java 7 platform?  It was end-of-lifed nearly two years ago.  https://www.infoq.com/news/2015/05/Oracle-Ends-Java-7Public-Updates

Comment: Tomcat 8 runs just fine on Java 8, and will run just fine on Java 9 ... when it is released.  If you stick with an old version of Java you will run into more and more difficulties like this.  And you are also putting system security at risk because security patches have stopped.

Comment: @ stephen i am work on product base project which is already develop in jdk5 using tomcat-5.5 but i want to check compatibility of project in tomcat-8.5.11 and jdk-7, so i want to compile project using jdk-7 insted of  jdk-5

Comment: Well ... like I said ... that is a bad idea.

Comment: And actually, your Question says Tomcat 8.5, not Tomcat 5.5

Comment: @Stephen C yes,i need to use tomcat-8.5.11 and jdk-7, Neon J2EE will not support JDK-7  but support of tomcat-8.5.11

Comment: You still haven't given a logical reason for using Java 7.  Why upgrade from Java 5 to Java 7?  Both Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 8.5 should work with Java 8.   But anyhow, you are asking for a IDE recommendation, and requests for recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: *Neon* requires Java 8 to run itself. It can still be used to *create* for Java 7. You just need to have both installed, make sure you run Eclipse using Java 8, and then configure the workspace and projects for Java 7. Your question doesn't include *where you are stuck* in this process, though.